# Parsing result of google maps api call to service

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm fairly new to Google Maps API...

I have a search box where I would like to present the user with a list of my clients branches.

So what I would like to do is:

1. OnChange on my input field I would like to call a service to get a search result (json?) from Google Maps (restricted by country)
2. Take the first result (lng/lat) from Google Maps and feed into a local procedure that returns branches based on geocode.

My main issue is to perform #1.

Can anyone provide me an example of how to do this? I have a running solution using the Autocomplete function from Google but I don't want to autocomplete an input field with results from Google Maps...

Hope it makes sense :-/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the examples given at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the place to start...